# to make a llist that have all zeros except the one column which should be value 1

Tags: python, numpy

can anyone help on this?
if i try this code,

```
 a = np.array([2,1,5],[2,5,3])
 b = np.zeros_like(a)
 c=b[np.arange(len(a)), a.argmax()] = 1
 print(c)
```

It gives error`too many Indices for array`
my motive is to make a list that gives me all columns zeros except the one that is highest in  the input Numpy array,and make it '1'.
output shoud be([0,0,1],[0,1,0])

Comment: `b[a.argmax()] = 1`?

Comment: ok it works,thank you so much.do i need to make any changes of the array is 2d??or it will still work fine because argmax by default consider a flattened array?

Comment: I am not sure about the expected behavior for 2D. So, can't comment.

Comment: You can always do `b.flat[a.argmax()] = 1`

Comment: If you want help with a 2d array, give an example with such an array.

Comment: Use `a.argmax(axis=1)` with your existing code : `b[np.arange(len(a)), a.argmax(1)] = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Code:

```
matrix = np.array([[2, 1, 5], [2, 5, 3]])
imax = matrix.argmax(1)
n_labels = np.size(matrix, 1)
onehot = np.eye(n_labels)[imax]
```

How it works, line by line:

1. Define the numpy array.
2. Get the index of the maximum value in each row.
3. Get the size of the matrix's row, `N`.
4. Create a `NxN` matrix (lets call it `M`), in which all the values are zero, except the main diagonal, which is 1. For each value `i` from step 2, select the row `i` from this new matrix `M`.